# LED of the F4 key is always on

Tags: lenovo

I recently bought a Lenovo T14 gen1 with AMD Ryzen 7.

I installed ubuntu 20.10 (in dual boot with windows) but the F4 key (mute microphone) is always on.

Is there a way to turn this LED off if microphone is off and turn it on if microphone is on ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the T14s AMD running Linux Mint 20.10 and have the same issue. What I did was go into 'alsamixer', then choose to turn the mic led completely off until I find a way to fix this issue.